# Syntax error with quantified expressions in XQuery, using 'some in satisfies'

Tags: xquery, zorba

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with the following query:

```
for $item in doc("rss.xml")//item
let $title := lower-case($item/title)
let $description := lower-case($item/description)
where contains($title, "keyword") or
  contains($description, "keyword") or
  some $category in $item/category 
    satisfies contains($category, lower-case("keyword"))
return <tr>
  <td>{data($item/title)}</td>
  <td>{data($item/pubDate)}</td>
  </tr>
```

I started to get a syntax error after adding the some satisfies condition:

```
some $category in $item/category 
        satisfies contains($category, lower-case("keyword"))
```

The syntax error I am getting is:

> static error [err:XPST0003]: invalid expression: syntax error, unexpected "$"

I am using Zorba to process the query, the rss.xml file contains an RSS feed. Like I said, the query works fine with just the two contains tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An extra pair of parentheses is necessary around the [`QuantifiedExpr`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#prod-xquery-QuantifiedExpr) for embedding it into the [`OrExpr`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#prod-xquery-OrExpr):

```
                                ... or
  (some $category in $item/category 
    satisfies contains($category, lower-case("keyword")))
return ...
```

[`QuantifiedExpr`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#prod-xquery-QuantifiedExpr) has a lower precedence than an [`OrExpr`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#prod-xquery-OrExpr). Look up [`OrExpr`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#prod-xquery-OrExpr) in an XQuery grammar and find that it requires a [`ParenthesizedExpr`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#prod-xquery-ParenthesizedExpr) for adding a [`QuantifiedExpr`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#prod-xquery-QuantifiedExpr).

Without the parentheses, `some` syntactically is a `QName` and `$` is not a valid continuation after that. So Zorba is right to complain, and any other XQuery parser would likely do the same.

Comment: Thank you. I also realized that I could start with WHERE SOME .. and then the OR Expressions.

Comment: Better use the parentheses when placing the QuantifiedExpr first, too. Otherwise you'll risk a slightly different result, because the OrExpr then is contained in the QuantifiedEpr. In your case this makes a difference when there is an `item` with no `category`. Note that `some $x in () satisfies true() or true()` results in `false`, whereas `(some $x in () satisfies true()) or true()` is `true`.